# Infinite carousel slider

Tags: javascript

I would like to implement simple carousel with for example 5 images (3 images per slide).

How is the best way to implement it infinitely.

For example when I load the page it shows: image 1, image 2, image 3,

On the next slide it shows 2-3-4 then 3-4-5, 4-5-1, 5-1-2 and so on.

I don't want code just a suggestion.

One way is to append the first element after the fifth, next append the second after it and so on.

Another way is to use transition - translateX without appending or prepending the elements.

Is there easier or more elegant way to implement it and which way is better way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: if all 5 images are already shown you don't need a carousel

Comment: I've edited it, my bad it shows 3 images per slide

Answer (score 0):

Modal arithmetic? E.g. have a loop that counts from 0 forever (we'll count slides 0 to 4, not 1 to 5).

Each slide is index mod 5. E.g. first time, obviously 0,1,2,3,4.

Second slide is 1,2,3,4,5, except 5 mod 5 is 0, so it's 1,2,3,4,0.

Etc.

Sixth slide is 6,7,8,9,10, except values mod 5 are 1,2,3,4,0 again.

Comment: Thanks, my question is to append the images with javascript or use transition which is more effective

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for suggestion, pop and push your array of showed images
when the carrousel is slided, pop the array then push the image on the array

Comment: Should I append elements or use transition to show the first image after the fifth?

Comment: You should append. Transition are not well loved by some explorers meanwhile append is a reliable javascript function, plus you can personnalise the append style !